# Search function only returning first letter in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I am writing a job filtering system in Vuejs and when the user enters a letter in the search bar, it only filters through the first letter instead of the whole word.

Imagine I have a list with item "Banana". If the user types "Banana" into the search bar, the item "Banana" is returned, since the search matches the list item. When the user just types a singular letter i.e. "B" it displays all items with the letter B. However when another letter is followed by that "Ba" it returns nothing.

Below is the code that is causing me problems:

```
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      searchQuery:'',
      selectedItem: null,
      isVisible: false,
      userArray: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUser() {
      const query = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
      if(this.searchQuery === "" ) {
        return this.userArray; 
      }
      return this.userArray.filter((user) => {
        return Object.values(user).some((word) => 
          String(word).toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
      });
    },
  },
```

Other aspects of this filter function are working (i.e. the ability to click on jobs) except this search function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend separation of all these filters - `filter`, `some` and `includes` and debug the code. This is how you may come to know where you are lagging behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work. Check your `v-model` directive.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data(){
    return{
      searchQuery:'',
      selectedItem: null,
      isVisible: false,
      userArray: [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "baz"}],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUser() {
      const query = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
      if(this.searchQuery === "" ) {
        return this.userArray; 
      }
      return this.userArray.filter((user) => {
        return Object.values(user).some((word) => 
          String(word).toLowerCase().includes(query)
        );
      });
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="searchQuery" />
  <p>{{filteredUser}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have checked the v-model directive and everything looks fine to me. However I am displaying user instead of filteredUser as when I display the latter, the user array is shown in each element. This is most likely due to me importing the array from a local json file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with the help of [`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) along with the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data(){
    return{
      searchQuery:'',
      selectedItem: null,
      isVisible: false,
      userArray: [{name: "Alpha"}, {name: "Beta"}, {name: "Basu"}, {name: "Amar"}],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUser() {
      const query = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
      if(!query) {
        return this.userArray; 
      }
      return this.userArray.filter(user => user.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(query));
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="searchQuery" />
  <p>{{ filteredUser }}</p>
</div>
```